# automatic \minitoc?

Tags: chapters, minitoc

I want to create a template for a team of writers that will provide automatic minitoc generation such that they will not need to manually add a \minitoc at the beginning of every chapter.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this? Can the command be added to the \chapter definition or otherwise caused to be triggered automagically whenever LaTeX encounters a new chapter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Redefine `\chapter` is not a bad idea. Just do it. :)

Comment: Thanks. I know enough about LaTeX programming to get myself in trouble. I tried this:
\let\OldChapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{\OldChapter{#1}{#2}\minitoc}

which worked except that it causes the TOC to be treated as chapter 1 and named '*" (asterisk). Is \chapter is called internally by \tableofcontents? Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\oldchapter\chapter
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{ s O{#3} m}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      % chapter is starred, no \minitoc
      \oldchapter*{#3}%
    }{%
      \oldchapter[#2]{#3}%
      \minitoc
    }%
  }
}


\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\chapter{title}
\section{title}

\chapter[short title]{title}
\section{title}

\chapter*{title}
\section*{title}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this; it worked. I scanned the xparse docs but still don't see what is happening in  {s O{#3} m}. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: @Ron Here a) `s` stands for an optional star (as first argument). If it's seen, then `<true code>` in `\IfBooleanTF{#1}{<true code>}{<false code>}` is used. b) `O{#3}` stands for an standard optional argument (`[...]`) with default value `#3`, and c) `m` stands for a standard mandatory argument `{...}`.

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification.

Comment: But if the first chapter is `chapter*{title}`, the minitoc is not right?

Comment: @user26992 Yes, see the comment `% chapter is starred, no \minitoc` in my example.

Comment: Thanks for your replay @muzimuzhi Z. I try to add `\adjustmtc` after the command `\oldchapter*{#3}%`, but it does't work.

Comment: @user26992 Why you need a mini-toc for unnumbered chapter? How is the sections in that chapter numbered or written to `.toc`? Perhaps you can post a new question which refers to this one, with a complete example.